# Why does the Jenkins build in node is offline from the beginning of the installation. It shows Disk space is too low error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, cicd

I have installed the jenkins on AWS EC2 t2.micro(8GB) with amazon linux. The installation is success but the build in node keeps showing offline. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, no use. Terminated and created a new instance but the issue wasn't fixed. I have used the same ec2 in the past and installed jenkins with no issue. I am still learning this tool and don't know whats causing this issue. Can someone help me to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: When you launch the instance there should be a console output that is written as the instance starts up. Click on the node in Jenkins and there should be a "console output" option on the left pane. This will show an error. Add this error to your question and we should be able to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have that in that option. I only see Status
"Configure"
"Build History"
"Load Statistics"
"Script Console" 
in the left pane. 

I have created a job to trigger a build so that I can see console output for the build, but unfortunately the build stays in "pending - waiting for next available executor".

Comment: I went to the node monitoring and updated the size of free temp space and its resolved.